# Passing parent resource id to a create action from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, resources

I have a `Forum` that has many `Topic`s. My routes are the following:

```
GET  /forums/:forum_id/topics/new => Topics#new
POST /topics                      => Topics#create
```

This is where my problem starts:

```
= form_for @topic do |topic_form|
```

This form maps to the `POST /topics` route.  A `forum_id` has to be provided in order to save the topic. It is available to the `new` action, but I can't find any way to pass it to the `create` action.

I tried changing the routes to:

```
GET  /forums/:forum_id/topics/new => Topics#new
POST /forums/:forum_id/topics     => Topics#create
```

But now the `forum_id` ended up outside the topic parameter hash:

```
{ topic: { title: "Test" }, commit: "Create Topic", forum_id: 1 }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most proper way is to route it like you did in the second example. And then in the create action you can first instantiate the forum to make sure it is valid and then create a topic from the forum. It could look something like this:

```
def create
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = @forum.topics.new(params[:topic])
  if @topic.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

This assumes that your Forum model has_many :topics

Comment: shouldn't that be `@topic = @forum.topics.build(params[:topic])`, or even use `create` instead of `build` and skip the call to save?

Comment: Both valid ways to go but I would never say that you should always use this instead of that, especially in Ruby and in Rails where there is often many different ways to achieve the same thing. I prefer to instantiate before create. And as to new or build, I don't know exactly the differences when used on associations but new has worked just as well as build for me.